# How to login in web api 2 with Individual User Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have created a web api 2 project with individual user authentication. User can successfully get registered by the pre-written register action of the Account Controller. but there is no login action by which user user can login. I have tried my own Login Action but haven't succeeded:

```
 public AspNetUser Users(userpass usps)
        {
            string username = usps.username;
            string password = usps.password;


            AspNetUsers AspNetUser = db.AspNetUsers
                    .Where(b => b.UserName == username && b.PasswordHash == password).FirstOrDefault();


            return AspNetUser;
        }
```

I know that asp.net identity generated password is impossible to decrypt but is there any way by which I can login. I have already tried my level best but haven't succeeded.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that your OWIN pipeline is not configured to come to this action controller when you press the login button on the UI.

Check your StartUp.cs and StartUp.Auth.cs